# How is mysqli_num_rows($query); in normal sql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, mysqli

im following this mini series from Adam Khoury - http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1294. And he is using mySQLi while I have normal mySQL. So im having alot of problems. Can someone please show me how is this converted in normal mySQL, please.

```
                    <?php
                    // Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
                        if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
                            include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
                            $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
                            $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
                            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
                            $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                            if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 24) {
                                echo 'characters';
                                exit();
                            }
                            if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
                                echo 'numbersFirst';
                                exit();
                            }
                            if ($uname_check > 0) {
                                echo 'notavailable';
                                exit();
                            } else {
                                echo 'available';
                                exit();
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <script>
                        function checkusername(){
                            var u = _("username").value;
                            if(u.value != ""){
                                //Colors: GOOD = #6b8e00; BAD = #a12; CHECKING = #d38d00;
                                var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index.php");
                                ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                                    if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true){
                                        _("username").style.border = "1px solid #d38d00";
                                        if (ajax.responseText == "available"){
                                            _("username").style.border = "1px solid #6b8e00";
                                        }
                                        else if (ajax.responseText == "characters"){
                                            _("username").style.border = "1px solid #d38d00";
                                        }
                                        else if (ajax.responseText == "numbersFirst"){
                                            _("username").style.border = "1px solid #d38d00";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            _("username").style.border = "1px solid #a12";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
```

So, when i try to change it to normal mySQL, it responde me the whole website code. So i don't know what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Why converting? Why not to write in mysqli?

Comment: my database dosnt connect to mysqli, it just connect to mysql

Comment: You are mistaken. mysqli can c0nnect to mysql as well

Answer (score -1):

The only real difference(besides improving security) between mysqli and mysql is names. You can almost do a replace of `mysqli` to `mysql` with little or no problems.

Comment: You'll also need to swap parameters around - mysqli_query needs the connection as the first parameter.

Comment: Note: little or no problems